# service exits after ssh disconnect

Tags: debian, ssh, systemd, teamspeak

The service works perfectely if I am not logged in, but if I connect with ssh and then disconnect the service gets terminated. The service belongs to the user to whom I ssh. This is my current ts3.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=TeamSpeak3Server

[Service]
User=user1
Group=staff
Type=forking
WorkingDirectory=/usr/local/bin/teamspeak3-server_linux_amd64
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/teamspeak3-server_linux_amd64/ts3server_startscript.sh start
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/teamspeak3-server_linux_amd64/ts3server_startscript.sh stop
PIDFile=/usr/local/bin/teamspeak3-server_linux_amd64/ts3server.pid
RestartSec=5
Restart=always
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have already tried changeing ExecStart to

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nohup /usr/local/bin/teamspeak3-server_linux_amd64/ts3server_startscript.sh start
```

Other services like openvpn survive the ssh logout.
After reconnection the status of the systemd process reads:

```
active (exited)
```

while the normal status is

```
active (running)
```

Could the cause of the problem be that the script which I execute calls another script which gets killed if the shell sends sighup meassages?
Thank you for your answers.

**Edit:**

the important part of ts3server_startscript.sh are as follows:

```
COMMANDLINE_PARAMETERS="${2}"
D1=$(readlink -f "$0")
BINARYPATH="$(dirname "${D1}")"
cd "${BINARYPATH}"
LIBRARYPATH="$(pwd)"
BINARYNAME="ts3server"

if [ -e "$BINARYNAME" ]; then
  if[ -x "$BINARYNAME" ]; then
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LIBRARYPATH}:${LD_LIBARY_PATH}"
  "./${BINARYNAME}" ${COMMANDLINE_PARAMETERS} > /dev/null &
  PID=$!
  ps -p ${PID} > /dev/null 2>&1
  if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
      echo "..."
  else
      echo $PID > ts3server.pid
  fi
```

So if I interpret that correctely the server is started in the console by

```
     "./${BINARYNAME}" ${COMMANDLINE_PARAMETERS} > /dev/null &
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stackexchange! You can [take the tour first](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and the learn [How to Ask a good question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Is there any command in your interactive session that _uses_ the service? Give us some pointer on the other script you are talking about.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "command in your interactive session thet uses the service". Do you want to know if I'm modifying the service while beeing logged in with ssh? To provocate a crash the only thing requiered is to login via ssh and then kill the session with "exit".

Comment: Instead of `"./${BINARYNAME}" ${COMMANDLINE_PARAMETERS} > /dev/null &` try `"nohup ./${BINARYNAME}" ${COMMANDLINE_PARAMETERS} < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1 &`. See also the good answers at "[Best way to make a shell script daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430330/best-way-to-make-a-shell-script-daemon)" on Stack Overflow.

Comment: when adding nohup the service is unable to start and reports: ts3.service: Unit entered failed state. ts3.service: Failed with result 'Resources'

Comment: Check carefully if in any of your startup script (e.g. `.tcshrc` or `.bashrc`) there is some command that interacts with your service.

Comment: Check you `.logout` file, does it kill some process?

Comment: Please add the result of running `grep 'KillUser' /etc/systemd/logind.conf` to your question, and

Comment: response from grep: #KillUserProcesses=no

Comment: I tried (./script.sh start &) &, then the server crashed after ssh logout, but came up again every minute or so. When logging back in the server was unstable and got restarted once a minute. I guess it has something to do with that the service no longer is able to tell if the server is running and tries to restart it.

Comment: Can find nothing in .bashrc which interacts with my service. I think this would happen to all services running on my user, processes of other users like openvpn remain untouched.

Comment: .bash_logout only contains a clear_console command